# Weird print() output in while() when trying TCP connection

Tags: python, python-3.x, tcp

The problem is: `print()` in `client()` only output one line, while I expect it to print several lines because the `while` loop it resides obviously run more than one time.

The problem occurs when I am testing the sample code given in book ***Foundations of Python Network Programming, 3rd Edition***. This sample code basically create a simple TCP server/client that process/send simple text capitalisation request.  Following is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Foundations of Python Network Programming, Third Edition
# https://github.com/brandon-rhodes/fopnp/blob/m/py3/chapter03/tcp_deadlock.py
# TCP client and server that leave too much data waiting
import argparse, socket, sys

def server(host, port, bytecount):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    sock.bind((host, port))
    sock.listen(1)
    print('Listening at', sock.getsockname())
    while True:
        sc, sockname = sock.accept()
        print('Processing up to 1024 bytes at a time from', sockname)
        n = 0
        while True:
            data = sc.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            output = data.decode('ascii').upper().encode('ascii')
            sc.sendall(output) # send it back uppercase
            n += len(data)
            print('\r %d bytes processed so far' % (n,), end=' ')
            sys.stdout.flush()
        print()
        sc.close()
        print('  Socket closed')

def client(host, port, bytecount):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    bytecount = (bytecount + 15) // 15 * 16 # round up to a multiple of 16
    message = b'CAP!' # 16-byte message to repeat over and over

    print('Sending', bytecount, 'bytes of data, in chunks of 16 bytes')
    sock.connect((host, port))
    sent = 0
    while sent < bytecount:
        sock.sendall(message)
        sent += len(message)
        # print('test')
        print('\r %d bytes sent' %(sent,), end=' ') # <-- THIS IS THE PROBLEMATIC PRINT()
        sys.stdout.flush()

    print()
    sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)

    print('Receiving all the data the server sends back')

    received = 0
    while True:
        data = sock.recv(42)
        if not received:
            print('  The first data received says', repr(data))
        if not data:
            break
        received += len(data)
        print('\r %d bytes received' %(received,), end=' ')

    print()
    sock.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    choices = {'client': client, 'server': server}
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Get deadlocked over TCP')
    parser.add_argument('role', choices=choices, help='which role to play')
    parser.add_argument('host', help='interface the server listens at;'
                        ' host the client sends to')
    parser.add_argument('bytecount', type=int, nargs='?', default=16,
                        help='number of bytes for client to send (default 16)')
    parser.add_argument('-p', metavar='PORT', type=int, default=1060,
                        help='TCP port (default 1060)')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    function = choices[args.role]
    function(args.host, args.p, args.bytecount)
```

After I have simply created server locally, I started my client with

> python listing3-2.py client 0.0.0.0

This is the output I get:

> Sending 32 bytes of data, in chunks of 16 bytes
>   32 bytes sent
>
> Receiving all the data the server sends back   The first data received
>   says b'CAP!CAP!CAP!CAP!CAP!CAP!CAP!CAP!'  32 bytes received

**From this output we know that the `while()` loop has run 8 times(because of 8 'CAP!'s)  but `print('\r %d bytes sent' %(sent,), end=' ')` has run only once. What is more strange to me is that `sys.stdout.flush()` doesn't work, despite the effort of the author who might have also noticed the problem.**

Something even more weird happens when I try to add one line of `print('test')` just before the problematic `print()`, see what happens?

> python listing3-2.py client 0.0.0.0
>
> Sending 32 bytes of data, in chunks of 16 bytes test
>   4 bytes sent test 
>   8 bytes sent test
>   12 bytes sent test
>   16 bytes sent test
>   20 bytes sent test
>   24 bytes sent test
>   28 bytes sent test
>   32 bytes sent 
>   Receiving all the data the server sends back   The first data received says
>   b'CAP!CAP!CAP!CAP!CAP!CAP!CAP!CAP!'  32 bytes received

With an additional `print()` just before, `print('\r %d bytes sent' %(sent,), end=' ')` run 8 times, though the structure of loop is absolutely unchanged. I am totally confused by the fact that adding a `print()` could bring such consequence. And I am also confused by the thought that `print()` method may have some strange characteristics if used in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the `\r` combined with `end=' '` in the print message.  That is a carriage return without linefeed, so all the lines print over each other.  The extra `print` adds a linefeed and they stop printing over each other.  Change it to `\n` to fix, or more simply:

```
print(sent,'bytes sent')
```

P.S. There is also a math error:

```
bytecount = (bytecount + 15) // 15 * 16
```

should be:

```
bytecount = (bytecount + 15) // 16 * 16
```